# Where is ORACLE_HOME set in AIX?

Tags: linux, bashrc, aix

In Linux I can set `ORACLE_HOME` in `.cshrc`. Where do I set this variable in AIX?

Comment: There's no such thing as "compiling" `.cshrc`. `source` only reads and executes that file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the C shell in AIX, then you would also set it in `~/.cshrc`.  If you are using a different shell (e.g., Korn shell, Bash, Bourne shell, etc.), then you would set it in a startup script that is specific to that shell.

Comment: Then where can I set alias names?

Comment: You define aliases in the startup script for the shell you are using.  If you are using the C shell, you would do it in `~/.cshrc`.  If you are using Bash, you would do it in `~/.bashrc`.  Each shell documents a startup script that it executes.  If the shell supports aliases (all do except the original Bourne shell), you would define your aliases in the startup script for that shell.